# How do i call difrent jTextareas in a loop?

Tags: java, loops, count

in my Keyboardclass i have 3 difrent jTextareas (jTextareas1, jTextareas2, jTextareas3).
Normaly i call them with keyboardwindow.jTextArea1.setText(); 
or keyboardwindow.jTextArea1.setBackground(); in my main.

But is there a way to use them in a loop in my main something like:

```
 for(int n=1; n<=4; n++){ 
       keyboardwindow.jTextAreai.setText();
 }
```

Comment: Yes, put them in an array or a `List` (or any kind of collection you want), then iterate over them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use an array or `List` to store the JTextArea objects.

```
JTextArea[] textAreas = new JTextArea[];
//initialize and assign the TextAreas inside a initialization method

for(JTextArea textAreaObj: textAreas){
     keyboardwindow.textAreaObj.setText();
}
```

Comment: `keyboardwindow.textAreaObj` shouldn't work as far as I'm aware. Since you already have the references, it's unnecessary anyway.